# Loading Clojure code in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, clojure

I have this kind of problem. I have Clojure code contained in Eclipse plug-in (denoted A) in *.clj files. I don't want AOT compilation. However, I need to load the clojure code from another Clojure plug-in B. This is possible when B depends on A. Clojure can easily access the classpath and everything works. But I want the plug-in A to be plugged as extension to B. But there is a problem because I could not find a way how to load a Clojure file contained in A from *.clj file contained in B. I would like to use the Clojure 'load' function which can load *.clj files from classpath but this function just cannot see contents of plug-in A event when I explicitely start the plug-in like this

```
 (org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform/getBundle "A")
```

**Reaction to Laurent's answer**

Laurent, thank you very much! This is very interesting. However, I think this mayby solves a harder problem then my original one. You discribed how to call clojure code from java plug-in which is totaly awesome. I need to call clojure code from clojure plug-in which I think may be easier. I imagine that I would create extension point and provide clojure functions like this

```
<extension point="transforms">
  <function namespace="my.nemaspace" fn="my-transform"/>
</extension>
```

So I do not need any magic with IExecutableExtensionFactory. I can read the extension registry from clojure code. What I cannot do is load the function specified in the extension. Is this doable or did I just misunderstood something? I noticed that you are using clojure.osgi. This looks cool, is there any documentation for that project?

Comment: You need to explicitly add the JAR for "Plugin B" to the classpath used by the Clojure runtime when launching "Plugin A." However, I don't use Eclipse, so I don't have specifics.

Comment: OK, so I reacted to your reaction in a separate answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution occured to me: it is possible, in Eclipse, despite what I said in my previous answer, to create cyclic dependencies between the classloaders!

Eclipse guys needed to introduce this so that certain types of libraries (log4j, etc.) could work in an OSGi environment (which is what Eclipse is based upon).

This requires to leverage the `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy` mechanism ([Third Party libraries and classloading](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbuddy_loading.html&cp=2_1_3_8)).

It's quite easy: if you want plugin B to see all classes and resources of plugin A, just add this to plugin B's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: dependent
```

The line above indicates that plugin B's classloader will be able to access what its dependents classloaders have access to.

I created a sample set of plugins named A and B where B has 2 commands (visible in the top menu) : the first applies a text transformation on the "hello" hard coded string by calling clojure code in B. The second dynamically loads an new text transformation from plugin A, so that when you invoke the first command again, you see the result of applying transformations from B and transformations from A.

In your case, it may not even be required to use Eclipse Extension Point / Extension mechanism at all, after all. It will all depend on how you intent plugin B to "discover" plugin A relevant information.

The github repository showing this in action: https://github.com/laurentpetit/stackoverflow-12689605

HTH,

-- 
Laurent

Answer (score 6):

The problem you're having with regards to classloaders is to be expected : if the dependencies of your Eclipse plugins/OSGi bundles are A -> B, with the Clojure jar bootstraped from B, then not being able to see resources of A from B is normal.

There can be no cycles among dependencies of Eclipse plugins, so there can be no cycles among classloader hierarchies.

This is the same problem that you would face if you were to write extensions to B from A with regular Eclipse machinery : plugin B would declare an interface, and an extension point. Then plugin A could implement the interface, and declare an extension to the extension point. This last part allows the Eclipse framework to do some tricks with the bundles: it sees that A declares an extension to B, thus instanciates a class from A implementing the interface declared in B (this works since A depends on B), and gives B the implementation instance from A which is also OK since it implements the interface in B !

(Not sure this is clear).

**Anyway, back to plugins written in Clojure.**
With Clojure, you don't have, out of the box, such separate environments provided by classloaders, because everything gets aggregated in one "Clojure environment" living in the classloader realm of the plugin embedding the clojure jar.
So one possibility would just be, when plugin A starts, to load the relevant namespaces from A. Then they would be loaded at the right time, and available to any other Clojure code.
Another possibility would be to use the Extension Point/Extension machinery. Eclipse provides a way to use "factories" to create instances of extension points. In Counterclockwise, we leverage this feature, and have a generic factory class (written in java, so no AOT) which takes care of loading the right namespace from the right bundle.

Here are more detail concerning how to extend extension points.

**An example from Counterclockwise:**
There is an existing Extension Point in the Eclipse framework for contributing hyperlink detectors for the Console contents. Counterclockwise extends this extension point to add nrepl hyperlinks.
In the java world, you would have to directly declare, in your extension, some class of yours which implements interface IPatternMatchListenerDelegate.
But with CCW, for probably the same reasons as you, I try to avoid AOT at all costs, so I can't give a java class name in the extension, or I would have either had to write it in java and compile it, or write a `gen-class` in Clojure and AOT-compile it.

Instead, CCW leverages a hidden gem of plugin.xml's possibilities: in almost every place, when you have to provide a class name, you can instead provide an instance of [IExecutableExtensionFactory](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIExecutableExtensionFactory.html) whose `create()` method will be called by the Eclipse framework to create an instance of the desired class.

This allowed me to write a generic class for calling into the Clojure world: I just use, in place of the class name I should have written, the class name [ccw.util.GenericExecutableExtension](https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/blob/master/ccw.util/src/java/ccw/util/GenericExecutableExtension.java)

Extract from [plugin.xml](https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/blob/master/ccw.core/plugin.xml#L25) :

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners">
<consolePatternMatchListener
   id="ccw.editors.clojure.nREPLHyperlink"
   regex="nrepl://[^':',' ']+:\d+">
    <class class="ccw.util.GenericExecutableExtension">
       <parameter
             name="factory"
             value="ccw.editors.clojure.nrepl-hyperlink/factory">
       </parameter>
    </class>
</consolePatternMatchListener>
```

Note the `class` attribute, and how I can give parameters to the factory via the `parameter` element (the factory has to implement interface [IExecutableExtension](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIExecutableExtension.html) for being able to be initialized with the parameters).

Finally, you can see that in namespace `ccw.editors.clojure.nrepl-hyperlink`, the function [factory](https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/blob/master/ccw.core/src/clj/ccw/editors/clojure/nrepl_hyperlink.clj#L27) is rather simple and just calls the [make](https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/blob/master/ccw.core/src/clj/ccw/editors/clojure/nrepl_hyperlink.clj#L20) function:

```
(defn make []
  (let [state (atom nil)]
    (reify org.eclipse.ui.console.IPatternMatchListenerDelegate
      (connect [this console]  (dosync (reset! state console)))
      (disconnect [this]       (reset! state nil))
      (matchFound [this event] (match-found event @state)))))

(defn factory "plugin.xml hook" [ _ ] (make))
```

Please note that I'm showing this as an example, and the relevant code in Counterclockwise is not ready to be released as an independant library "ready for consumption".
But you should nonetheless be able to roll your own solution (it's quite easy once you get all the pieces in place in your head).

Hope that helps,

-- 
Laurent

Comment: Hi Laurent, thank you very much for you insight. Actually the solution you mentioned at the and of the answer seems very interesting. Generaly a best way for me would be if I could somehow create extension point where clojure plug-in would plug a function, or namespace. So if you could provide more detail that would be great.

Comment: Your first solution is to load namespace when the plug-in is starting. By that, you mean calling the RT.load function from the plug-in's Activator?

Comment: Hi, would you please tell us more about the detail of what you're trying to achieve, the options that are still open, those that are not, so that my answer can be more to the point and less vague/general?

Comment: Ok, what I need is this. I need to combine several transformations contributed by plug-ins written in clojure. The best solution would be that in my core clojure plug-in I define an extension point which allows contributing clojure functions. Plug-ins extending the core plug-in would then contribute clojure functions which will be called from the core plug-in. This should be possible without AOT compilation. Is that clear enough?

Comment: I've just added explanations on how this is done in Counterclockwise.

Comment: Thank you Luarent. I altered my question so its more clear what I want to do.

Comment: Hi Laurent, I finally got to implementation of you solution with the Eclispe-Buddy parameter and it WORKS! Thank you very much. You helped to solve one of the most painful issues of our project. I appriciate what you are doing with you counteclockwise plug-in for Eclipse. I would like to send you some donation.